# De-reference error when printing the item pointed to by head in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to print the item of the node pointed to by head, but I end up with a 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct nodeStruct’ error. 
Code that is not shown includes the list.h file and other functions of the class.

Relevant Code:
List.c:

```
struct nodeStruct {
    int item;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
};
/*
 * Allocate memory for a node of type struct nodeStruct and initialize
 * it with the value item. Return a pointer to the new node.
 */
struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int item) {
    struct nodeStruct *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeStruct));
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    printf("New node created with item %d\n", newNode->item);
    return newNode;
}


/*
 * Insert node at the head of the list.
 */
void List_insertHead (struct nodeStruct **headRef, struct nodeStruct *node) {
    if(*headRef == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty, creating new head\n");
        *headRef = node;
        printf("Empty list new head: %d\n", (*headRef)->item);
    }
    // Head already exists, shift pointer of head to new node
    // and change new head pointer to old head
    else {
        struct nodeStruct* oldHead = *headRef;
        printf("Old head item: %d\n", oldHead->item);
        node->next = *headRef;
        *headRef = node;
        printf("New Head: %d // Old head: %d\n", (*headRef)->item, node->next->item);
    }
}
```

test_list.c:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("Starting tests...\n");
struct nodeStruct* head = NULL;

// Create 1 node:
struct nodeStruct* firstNode = List_createNode(0);
List_insertHead(&head, firstNode);
printf("%d\n", head->item); // error
```

Makefile:

```
CC=cc
CXX=CC
CCFLAGS= -g -w -std=c99 -Wall -Werror



all: test_list test

# Compile all .c files into .o files
# % matches all (like * in a command)
# $< is the source file (.c file)
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<


test_list: list.o test_list.o
    $(CC) -o test_list list.o test_list.o

test: test_list
    ./test_list


clean:
    rm -f core *.o test_list
```

The purpose for printing head->item is to see whether or not the head is functioning correctly.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this is an issue with how it's being compiled. Could you show how you're compiling this? Do you have a header file?

Comment: @Schwern Hello, I am compiling using a makefile. As for the header file, i have declarations for all my other function prototypes.

Comment: Could you [edit this into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52462627/edit), please? It's easier to read and easier for other people to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a header file.

C compiles each source file into object files separately. Then it links them together. Each .c file must know the signature of all types and functions it uses. That means `test_list.c` must know the signatures of the structs and functions in `list.c`. Currently it does not.

You could directly include `list.c` in `test_list.c` with `#include list.c` which basically pastes `list.c` into `test_list.c`. This will work, but then `list.c` cannot be used by any other file without causing all sorts of problems.

Better is to make a [header file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm) which declares all your types and [forward declares](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Forward_declaration) all your functions. A forward declaration let's the compiler know what functions are available and what their signature is, with a promise that something else will define the function later.

```
// list.h

struct nodeStruct {
    int item;
    struct nodeStruct *next;
};

struct nodeStruct* List_createNode(int);
void List_insertHead (struct nodeStruct **, struct nodeStruct *);
```

Now both `test_list.c` and `list.c` can `#include "list.h"` to give the compiler enough information to compile each source file into an object file. Then the objects will be linked together and tell test_list.o where to find the functions in list.o.

```
# Compile list.c into list.o using the declarations in list.h
cc -c -g -w -std=c99 -Wall -Werror list.c

# Compile test_list.c into test_list.o using the declarations in list.h
cc -c -g -w -std=c99 -Wall -Werror test_list.c

# Link both object files into an executable so test_list.o can
# use the functions compiled into list.o
cc -o test_list list.o test_list.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine:

see the results:

```
Starting tests...
New node created with item 0
List is empty, creating new head
Empty list new head: 0
0
```

Maybe is something with your compiling process.

Comment: Hello Eduardo, do you know at which part in my Makefile the error arises from?

Comment: not exactly, try to remove -std=c99 ...
 My suggestion is try to build a more simple make file without transformations ... or try to do what is it doing by hand to find out the problem.

Comment: Try to put your struct in .h file